# ruby on rails TypeError in Users#show - Cannot visit Like

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, typeerror

*form that causes the problem:*

```
<%= form_for Like.find(post.user.likes), :html => { :method => :delete , :class => "unlike_post_like_form" } do |f| %>
```

**Post model**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :likes
```

**User model**

```
  has_many :posts
  has_many :likes
```

**Like model**

```
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
```

i keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError in Users#show 
Cannot visit Like
```

on

```
Like.find(post.user.likes),
```

**EDIT:**

**First solution:**

changing

```
Like.find(post.user.likes),
```

to

```
Like.find(post.user.likes).limit(1),
```

**Second solution:**

changing

```
Like.find(post.user.likes),
```

to

```
current_user.likes.where(:post_id => post.post_id)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Like.find(post.user.likes)` is attempting to find a `Like` given an array of `likes`. That doesn't really make much sense.

Most likely, you'll want to search `post.user.likes`, but even then, I'm a bit confused - you'll need to post more code.

`Like.find` is looking for either an id (integer), or a hash containing keys and values. An array doesn't give it any information to search.

**EDIT:** If you're looking for the likes of current user. You'll need to do the following...

`current_user.likes.where(:post => @post)`

Comment: @fxuser whose `like.id`? A post has many likes, as you have defined. Maybe `current_user`?

Comment: i meant current_user... aka mine

Comment: @fxuser edited my original comment with the following: `current_user.likes.where(:post => @post)`

Answer (score 1):

The type error comes from passing a collection (`post.user.likes` - which is an array) into a method that's expecting a record id, for example, `Likes.find(3)` or `Likes.find(params[:id])`

Comment: We can "find" a collection of resources, too:

`> User.find([2, 3])`
`=> [#<User id: 2, ...>, #<User id: 3, ...>]`