# Simple Rails App: Error Cannot visit Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to build a simple Rails app. Rails v3.2.22.5 (it is a requirement). I am running it with PostgreSQL. When I start the server however I get the following error when I try to read a simple Post from the database.

> Cannot visit Integer

The trace leads me to the show method below. More specifically to the second line. I am very new to Rails and have absolutely no clue as to how to fix this. Searched the web already without success. Any ideas would be most welcome.

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end
```

Full trace:

```
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:25:in `rescue in visit'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:241:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_Limit'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:123:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:19:in `accept'
activerecord (3.2.22.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `to_sql'
activerecord (3.2.22.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:60:in `select_all'
activerecord (3.2.22.5) lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
activerecord (3.2.22.5) lib/active_record/explain.rb:41:in `logging_query_plan'
activerecord (3.2.22.5) lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
activerecord (3.2.22.5) lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
activerecord (3.2.22.5) lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
activerecord (3.2.22.5) lib/active_record/explain.rb:34:in `logging_query_plan'
activerecord (3.2.22.5) lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
activerecord (3.2.22.5) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:381:in `find_first'
activerecord (3.2.22.5) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:122:in `first'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:16:in `show'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.22.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__2562463311931153568__process_action__1655262725222060869__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.22.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.22.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.22.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.22.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.22.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.22.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.22.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:46:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.22.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.22.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.22.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2325253408966325104__call__3112622970942194936__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.22.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.22.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.22.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.22.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.22.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.22.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.22.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.22.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:83:in `call'
railties (3.2.22.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
railties (3.2.22.5) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.22.5) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/luishreis/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
/Users/luishreis/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
/Users/luishreis/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:290:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: What URL are you using to get the page for a particular post?

Comment: @SunilD. http://localhost:3000/posts/1

Comment: Why the weird version requirement if you are building from scratch? `v3.2.22.5` is ancient and insecure.

Comment: Can you post the full error log? That controller action looks fine to me by itself. What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: Try `@post = Post.where(id: params[:id]).first`

Comment: @SivaPraveen No luck =(

Comment: @Puhlze Updated the question with the full trace. Thank you.

Comment: @max It is for a job  interview. They have legacy code they are maintaining and need us to be prepared for such scenarios.

Comment: After a few attempts at debugging this money is at `params[:id]`. But no luck. Same error pops up every time.

Comment: Have you checked the incoming params? Could it be that `params[:id]` is an array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333466/ruby-on-rails-typeerror-in-usersshow-cannot-visit-like

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The version of Ruby you're using (2.4.1) is not compatible with the version of Rails you're using (3.2.22.5). That version of Ruby requires at least Rails 5. Try downgrading to Ruby 2.3 or lower. You can use a Ruby version manager (i.e. `rvm`, `rbenv` or `chruby`) to control which Ruby is used when launching your application.

## Edit

Just noticed you're already using `rbenv` from your stack trace. Add a `.ruby-version` file to your application's directory containing the following line:

```
2.3.4
```

Once you re-enter that directory, confirm the version via:

```
$> ruby -v
ruby 2.3.4p301 (2017-03-30 revision 58214) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

(or similar version) before launching rails.

Comment: Worked brilliantly. Thank you.

Comment: you have saved my day. rbenv 2.3.4

Comment: Do you have a good resource of where it says Ruby 2.4.1 is not compatible with Rails 3.2.22.5. All that I've come across just say Rails 3.2 can use Ruby 2.2 or newer, etc.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Unfortunately no. There is no way to know ahead of time how changes in Ruby may affect Rails. That's why tools like rvm and rbenv exist. They allow you to travel back in time and use unsupported versions without messing with your system Ruby. The Ruby and Rails versions used in the parent comment were both past EOL support and should be upgraded.

Comment: The [CI config for Rails 3](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/.travis.yml) is a good indicator of supported versions. It ranges from 1.8 to 2.3.

Answer (score 44):

I got this error yesterday and created a workaround which should make it work with ruby 2.4 and rails 3.2. This also is confirmed to work with `ruby 2.5.9p229` and `Rails 3.2.22.5`.

The commit that I got the idea from is at:
https://github.com/rails/arel/commit/dc85a6e9c74942945ad696f5da4d82490a85b865

Just include the following in your rails initializers.

```
module Arel
  module Visitors
    class DepthFirst < Arel::Visitors::Visitor
      alias :visit_Integer :terminal
    end

    class Dot < Arel::Visitors::Visitor
      alias :visit_Integer :visit_String
    end

    class ToSql < Arel::Visitors::Visitor
      alias :visit_Integer :literal
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't work for me on Rails 3.2.22.5 and Ruby 2.4.3. I get the following error when trying to launch the console: `activerecord-3.2.22.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:269: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
arel-3.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:25:in `rescue in visit': Cannot visit Integer (TypeError)`

Comment: This works for me. My ruby version is '2.0.0p247' and rails version is '3.2.22.5'.

Comment: Just coming back here 6 years later to say that this ended up solving my problem on `ruby 2.5.9p229` and `Rails 3.2.22.5`. Thanks for this and sorry for the initial downvote .

Answer (score 10):

For future Googlers. I had the same problem but I needed to apply a variant of Thomas Dziedzic solution.

I have `ruby 2.5.1` and `rails 4.2.10` running in my system.

As shown in [this commit](https://github.com/rails/arel/commit/a6a7c75ff486657909e20e2f48764136caa5e87e#diff-a044319ea18758df55167af00a0250d9R17) ToSql was changed from `Arel::Visitors::Visitor`to `Arel::Visitors::Reduce`

So this is my updated solution. In a rails initializer put this:

```
module Arel
  module Visitors
    class DepthFirst < Arel::Visitors::Visitor
      alias :visit_Integer :terminal
    end

    class Dot < Arel::Visitors::Visitor
      alias :visit_Integer :visit_String
    end

    class ToSql < Arel::Visitors::Reduce
      alias :visit_Integer :literal
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There is only one difference. The one I explain briefly above. `class ToSql < Arel::Visitors::Reduce` instead of `class ToSql < Arel::Visitors::Visitor` And it's due to the Rails version