# Could not find table (following upgrade to newer Ruby and Rails versions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I had an app (based on [this tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app)) that used to work. However, I now get the error:

> Could not find table 'users'

I had to upgrade the version of Ruby I was using (from 2.0.0 to 2.4.4). With the newer Ruby version, I also had to use newer versions of some of the gems the app uses. In particular, a newer version of sqlite3 which manages the app's database.

Is the new sqlite3 the reason the table can no longer be found? What can I do to resolve the error? I assume upgrading the gem version did not delete the data the table previously contained...

Comment: You can use simple command `RAILS_ENV=development rails db:setup` instead of `RAILS_ENV=development rails db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQLite and there's no `db/development.sqlite3` file, something happened with it and you'll have to recreate your database. If this is the development environment and you can clean the database, run the following command:

```
RAILS_ENV=development rails db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

This is going to recreate the database, run the migrations and the `seeds.rb` file.

Note: by default, Rails creates the `.gitignore` file excluding `.sqlite3` files. This is going to prevent the SQLite database to be versioned.

Comment: Oh. I git cloned the repository so my `db/development.sqlite3` was indeed empty! I managed to get a copy of the original file and copied and pasted it there. I am now getting a `Cannot visit Integer` error. Searching around shows that the [error might be due to a Rails version incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44102011/2354735). Does that mean that the contents of the `db/development.sqlite3` file is not generic but somehow specific to a Rails/Ruby version and I can't simply copy&paste? I.e. is there no way to use my old data with the newer gems?

Comment: @JetBlue The database file is normally ignored, because it's data. You can take a db:dump and reload it, but in general you wouldn't want to shuffle around the binary DB data as the file format may change etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks, how would I do a `db:dump`?

Comment: Turns out the `Cannot visit Integer` error was not related to the database.

Comment: @JetBlue I don't remember. It might be a gem.